# Celery Beat - Pyramid Mailer

Tags: celery, pyramid, celerybeat

So, I have some plain python code which works pefectly in a normal python shell:

```
from pyramid_mailer.mailer import Mailer
from pyramid_mailer.message import Message
from pyramid_mailer.message import Attachment

mailer = Mailer(
    host="172.10.10.240",
    port="25")
message = Message(
subject="Orders with invalid status",
sender='r@example.com'],
recipients=['luke@example.com'],
html="<p>Test</p>")
mailer.send_immediately(message)
```

But, If I create a celery beat task such as this:

```
from pyramid_celery import celery_app as app
from pyramid_mailer.mailer import Mailer
from pyramid_mailer.message import Message
from pyramid_mailer.message import Attachment

mailer = Mailer(
    host="172.10.10.240",
    port="25")

@app.task
def wronglines_celery():
    message = Message(
    subject="Orders with invalid status",
    sender='r@example.com'],
    recipients=['luke@example.com'],
    html="<p>Test</p>")
    mailer.send_immediately(message)
```

This second example does not generate an email, it runs perfectly fine and throws no error at all, even with the log level set to DEBUG.

Running celery beat with:

```
celery beat -A pyramid_celery.celery_app --ini development.ini
```

Using the pyramid_celery plug-in as referenced in the official documentation on the celery website. My development.ini file can be seen below (relevant parts):

```
[celery]
BROKER_URL = amqp://app_rmq:password@localhost:5672/myvhost
CELERY_IMPORTS = intranet.celery_tasks

# Check once a day for orders with wrong line status
[celerybeat:task1]
task = intranet.celery_tasks.wronglines_celery
type = crontab
schedule = {"hour": 16, "minute": 30}

[logger_celery]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = celery


# Begin logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root, intranet, sqlalchemy, celery
```

EDIT:

If I launch celery (without beat) it works perfectly, e.g. if I launch with:

```
celery worker -A pyramid_celery.celery_app --ini development.ini
```

All tasks execute (over and over) but all emails send and nothing throws an error, it seems to be the introduction of beat which is causing issues.

Comment: Add a debugger breakpoint inside the function and step through it. Otherwise everything done here is guesswork and no progress on this question can be made. https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after much googlig and frustrating debugging I found [an old github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2059). That claimed celery tasks were working only when launched with a worker, and not with beat. The user states

> Beat does not execute tasks, it just sends the messages. You need both a beat instance and a worker instance!

So to launch the work and the beat instance with the same command, shown here:

```
celery worker --beat -A pyramid_celery.celery_app --ini development.ini
```

I will be sending a pull request today to fix the documentation with regards to the correct way to launch a worker and beat instance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its not working?  The way we've configured your crontab it says "Only run once a day at 4:30".  So if you ran that until it hit 4:30 I would expect it to execute properly.

Can you change your `schedule` to be `{}` instead to have it run every minute as a basic test?

I've added a crontab example to the examples here:

https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_celery/blob/master/examples/scheduler_example/development.ini#L33-L36

If you can provide more code (maybe a sample repo or modification of the examples already in the repo) that shows it not working I can take a look and hopefully fix the bug.

Comment: Yes, I changed this for testing, see my answer re the documentation for launching beat with a worker.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [Celery tasks silently fail on error output](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_celery/pull/50). It most likely throws an exception which you never seen.

To be sure what's going to fail, put pdb (ipdb) breakpoint in task code, start celery worker on the foreground and step through the code line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure it must be failing silently, so, I have copied my entire app task into its own python file, used the same imports as my celery task file, and when run through python standalone, no error, works perfectly. However, when I run in celery, it throws no error at all, even with the configuration of my logging file as you suggested.

Comment: Also, If I run the celery with "celery worker -A pyramid_celery.celery_app --ini development.ini" the code works fine, it seems to be celery beat that is causing the problems.

Comment: from celery.contrib import rdb
rdb.set_trace()

Then you can telnet into a debugger in the real worker process.